# How can I recreate this 2d surface + contour + glyph plot in R?

Tags: r, graphics, plot, visualization

I've run a 2d simulation in some modelling software from which i've got an export of x,y point locations with a set of 6 attributes. I wish to recreate a figure that combines the data, like this:
[image]

The ellipses and the background are shaded according to attribute 1 (and the borders of these are of course representing the model geometry, but I don't think I can replicate that), the isolines are contours of attribute 2, and the arrow glyphs are from attributes 3 (x magnitude) and 4 (y magnitude).

The x,y points are centres of the triangulated mesh I think, and look like this:
[image]

I want to know how I can recreate a plot like this with R. To start with I have irregularly-spaced data due to it being exported from an irregular mesh. That's immediately where I get stuck with R, having only ever used it for producing box-and-whisper plots and the like.

Here's the data:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22417033/Ellipses_noheader.txt
Edit: fields: x, y, heat flux (x), heat flux (y), thermal conductivity, Temperature, gradT (x), gradT (y).

```
names(Ellipses) <- c('x','y','dfluxx','dfluxy','kxx','Temps','gradTx','gradTy')
```

Comment: A description of the data and how it was created would help a whole lot. There are no headers.

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DWin is right to say that your graph don't represent faithfully your data, so I would advice to follow his answer. However here is how to reproduce (the closest I could) your graph:

```
Ellipses <- read.table(file.choose())
names(Ellipses) <- c('x','y','dfluxx','dfluxy','kxx','Temps','gradTx','gradTy')
require(splancs)
require(akima)
```

First preparing the data:

```
#First the background layer (the 'kxx' layer):
# Here the regular grid on which we're gonna do the interpolation
E.grid <- with(Ellipses, 
               expand.grid(seq(min(x),max(x),length=200),
                           seq(min(y),max(y),length=200)))
names(E.grid) <- c("x","y") # Without this step, function inout throws an error
E.grid$Value <- rep(0,nrow(E.grid))
#Split the dataset according to unique values of kxx
E.k <- split(Ellipses,Ellipses$kxx)
# Find the convex hull delimiting each of those values domain
E.k.ch <- lapply(E.k,function(X){X[chull(X$x,X$y),]}) 
for(i in unique(Ellipses$kxx)){ # Pick the value for each coordinate in our regular grid
    E.grid$Value[inout(E.grid[,1:2],E.k.ch[names(E.k.ch)==i][[1]],bound=TRUE)]<-i
}

# Then the regular grid for the second layer (Temp)
T.grid <- with(Ellipses,
               interp(x,y,Temps, xo=seq(min(x),max(x),length=200),        
                      yo=seq(min(y),max(y),length=200), 
                      duplicate="mean", linear=FALSE))
# The regular grids for the arrow layer (gradT)
dx <- with(Ellipses,
           interp(x,y,gradTx,xo=seq(min(x),max(x),length=15),
                  yo=seq(min(y),max(y),length=10),
                  duplicate="mean", linear=FALSE))
dy <- with(Ellipses,
           interp(x,y,gradTy,xo=seq(min(x),max(x),length=15),
                  yo=seq(min(y),max(y),length=10),
                  duplicate="mean", linear=FALSE))
T.grid2 <- with(Ellipses,
               interp(x,y,Temps, xo=seq(min(x),max(x),length=15),        
                      yo=seq(min(y),max(y),length=10), 
                      duplicate="mean", linear=FALSE))
gradTgrid<-expand.grid(dx$x,dx$y)
```

And then the plotting:

```
palette(grey(seq(0.5,0.9,length=5)))
par(mar=rep(0,4))
plot(E.grid$x, E.grid$y, col=E.grid$Value, 
     axes=F, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", pch=19)
contour(T.grid, add=TRUE, col=colorRampPalette(c("blue","red"))(15), drawlabels=FALSE)
arrows(gradTgrid[,1], gradTgrid[,2],  # Here I multiply the values so you can see them
       gradTgrid[,1]-dx$z*40*T.grid2$z, gradTgrid[,2]-dy$z*40*T.grid2$z, 
       col="yellow", length=0.05)
```

[image]

To understand in details how this code works, I advise you to read the following help pages: `?inout`, `?chull`, `?interp`, `?expand.grid` and `?contour`.

Comment: For me this answer best answers the question, even though the ones by @Dwin and Greg Snow give great advice and tips too. Would be nice to split the points, but I'll go with this one.

Answer (score 7):

It's quite easy to make the lower plot (making the assumption that there is a dataframe named 'edat' read in with:

```
 edat <- read.table(file=file.choose())
 with(edat, plot(V1,V2), cex=0.2)
```

[image]

Things get a bit more beautiful with:

```
with(edat, plot(V1,V2, cex=0.2, col=V5))
```

[image]

So I do not think your original is being faithfully represented by the data. The contour lines are NOT straight across the "conductors".  I call them "conductors" because this looks somewhat like iso-potential lines in electrostatics. I'm adding some text here to serve as a search handle for others who might be searching for plotting problems in real world physics: vector-field (the arrows) , heat equations, gradient, potential lines.
You can then overlay the vector field with:

```
with(edat, arrows(V1,V2, V1-20*V6*V7, V2-20*V6*V8, length=0.04, col="orange") )
```

[image]

You could"zoom in" with xlim and ylim:

```
with(edat, plot(V1,V2, cex=0.3, col=V5, xlim=c(0, 10000), ylim=c(-8000, -2000) ))
with(edat, arrows(V1,V2, V1-20*V6*V7, V2-20*V6*V8, length=0.04, col="orange") )
```

[image]

Guessing that the contour requested if for the Temps variable. Take your pick of contourplots.

```
require(akima)
intflow<- with(edat, interp(x=x, y=y, z=Temps, xo=seq(min(x), max(x), length = 410), 
              yo=seq(min(y), max(y), length = 410), duplicate="mean", linear=FALSE) )

require(lattice)
contourplot(intflow$z)
filled.contour(intflow)
with( intflow, contour(x=x, y=y, z=z) )
```

[image]

The last one will mix with the other plotting examples since those were using base plotting functions. You may need to switch to `points` instead of `plot`.

Comment: Thanks, good tips! I'm still no wiser how I can interpolate my irregular data onto a regular grid though. Any tips for that?

Comment: This is the wisdom of @GregSnow regarding `akima::interp` put into practice.

Answer (score 3):

There are several parts to your plot so you will probably need several tools to make the different parts.

The background and ellipses can be created with `polygon` (once you figure where they should be).

The `contourLines` function can calculate the contour lines for you which you can add with the `lines` function (or `contour` has and `add` argument and could probably be used to add the lines directly).

The akima package has a function `interp` which can estimate values on a grid given the values ungridded.

The `my.symbols` function along with `ms.arrows`, both from the TeachingDemos package, can be used to draw the vector field.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on your package @greg. I calculated the angle required for ms.arrows by `arrow.angle <- atan2(x=dfluxx, y=dfluxy)`. The arrows so far look pretty flexible in size and shape, but it's a slow process going through the options to discover the best 'settings'.

Comment: @adifferentben, What could have been included in the documentation that would have made this clearer to you?  It is probably better to respond via e-mail (included in the help file) than make this a long comment conversation that most will not care about.